# java regular expression get substring

Tags: java, regex

I can't find any good resource for parsing with regular expression. Could someone please show me the way.

How can I parse this statement?

> "Breakpoint 10, main () at file.c:10"

I want get the substring "main ()" or 3rd word of the statement.

Comment: please define under which criteria you want to get this result

Comment: Not enough details. Do you want to get the 3rd word of your string? Or what is always contained in "Breakpoint 10, * at file.c:10"? Or anything else?

Comment: Do you want to find the exact string `main()` or any method name that could possibly contain parameters as well? Anyways, regular-expressions.info has a good regex reference and quite some tutorials (even Java specific ones).

Comment: @Guillaume yes, 3rd word of the string..

Comment: I'd suggest a Tokenizer, then, see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
public void test1() {
    String text = "Breakpoint 10, main () at file.c:10";
    String regex = ",(.*) at";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Basically the regular expression `.(.*) at` with *group(1)* returns the value `main ()`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the **3rd word of your string** (as said in your comments), first break it using a `StringTokenizer`. That will allow you to specify separator (space is by default)

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
String str = "Breakpoint 10, main () at file.c:10";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str); // space by default

while(st.hasMoreElements()){
    words.add(st.nextToken());
}

String result = words.get(2);
```

That returns `main`
If you also want the `()`, as you defined spaces as separator, you also need to take the next word `words.get(3)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [standard Sun tutorial on regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) ? In particular the section on [matching groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) would be of use.

Answer (score 1):

1. Good website [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
2. Good online tester [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/)
3. Java http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

I turn to these when I want to play with Regex

Answer (score 0):

Try: `.*Breakpoint \d+, (.*) at`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the regular expression `main \(\)` does parse this. However, I suspect that you would like everything after the first comman and before the last "at": `,(.*) at` gives you that in *group(1)* that is opened by the parenthesis in the expression.